# iOS store just a little bit of data

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I was wondering if there is a way to store small amounts of data, without going to a full-blown core-data API.  I just need to store 6 'double' values somewhere...  What's the best approach for that?

Thanks, Alex.

Comment: Retagged to include both Cocoa and Cocoa Touch. The two frameworks are basically the same w.r.t. storing data.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Core Data is just one way to store data, and it only makes sense when you need the things that it does. Here are five good options for storing your data:

- Use `NSUserDefaults`. (Dead simple.)
- Store the data in an appropriate structure (say, `NSDictionary`) and store it as a property list. (Pretty darn easy.)
- Store the data in a class of your own design that implements `NSCoding`, and then write an instance of that class to a file using `NSKeyedArchiver`. (Works well for storing entire object graphs; this is basically what IB does. It might take an hour or two for the light to come on, but once you understand it this is a very nice way to read and write objects.)
- Use Cocoa Touch's file system API, notably `NSFileHandle` and `NSFileManager`. (Conceptually simple if you've ever worked with a file system before. Puts you in complete control.)
- Use the regular old POSIX file system API. (Best for existing Unix code, or code that you also want to compile on other platforms.)

Before you jump into any of those, read Apple's *[Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1)*, *[User Defaults Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html)*, and *[File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)*.

Comment: @geekyaleks: It definitely is easy. `double d = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"somekey"];`

Answer (score 5):

You can use NSUserDefaults to accomplish that (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
-(void)saveToUserDefaults:(NSString*)myString
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (standardUserDefaults) {
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:myString forKey:@"Prefs"];
        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
    }
}

-(NSString*)retrieveFromUserDefaults
{
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *val = nil;

    if (standardUserDefaults) 
        val = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"Prefs"];

    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to store small amounts of data without using some of the larger API's is the [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. It's really easy to set up and use.